# Verbatim date entry

Tags: biblatex, biber, date

I received a bibliography (docx) with the following entry that I’m trying to fit into LaTeX:

> Bo Ming, Fengcheng suolu, presumably first published in late Qianlong era. Liaohai congshu, Shenyang: Liaoshen shushe, 1986: 273-283.

I created a bibliography entry, here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
@incollection{bo1986,
    author={Bo, Ming},
    title = {Fengcheng suolu},
    date = {1986 [presumably first published in late Qianlong era]},
    booktitle = {Liaohai congshu},
    location = {Shenyang},
    publisher = {Liaoshen shushe},
    pages = {273--283}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{literature}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Biber warns about the date entry being invalid and ignores the date, resulting in (n.d.) in the bibliography.
How can I add `presumably first published in late Qianlong era` to the publication date?

Answer (score 0):

Use `year` (which is a literal field) instead of `date`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
@incollection{bo1986,
    author={Bo, Ming},
    title = {Fengcheng suolu},
    year = {1986 [presumably first published in late Qianlong era]},
    booktitle = {Liaohai congshu},
    location = {Shenyang},
    publisher = {Liaoshen shushe},
    pages = {273--283}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{literature}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The biblatex manual recommends against using `year` and advocates the `date` field, but the latter doesn’t take text verbatim.
Using the (legacy) `year` field, biber also warns that the entry will probably not sort properly, but it looks as intended in the pdf.

Comment: I don't think that misusing year is a good idea. Try with `\usepackage{biblatex}` and `\cite{bo1986}` to see the problem. Imho it would be better to use e.g. the note field.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I understand that misusing a legacy field for this purpose is not a desirable (nor permanent) solution, and I can imagine potential issues with the cite command and entries in such a case. However, using the above file, but without \nocite{*} and with \cite{bo1986} instead, seems to work just as well.